# How can I get average of sales for each week within each year?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to get the average sales for each week for each year, I have used :

```
weekavg <- aggregate(dod$Amount,list(dod$week),mean)
```

where dod is the name of my df as shown in the picture below.

The result gives me a list with just 53 rows ie for just 53 weeks - total for a single year.

How can I get the o/p such that it shows for each year ie 53 + 52 + 52 = 157 rows say for 3 years. I know my data is incomplete and does not entirely have 157 weeks, but I would like to know the logic so I can implement it. Any help would be appreciated.

dod:

```
Date    Amount year month      wday week wdayno
1     4/1/2015  38086.24 2015     4 Wednesday   13      3
2     4/2/2015  35426.65 2015     4  Thursday   14      4
3     4/3/2015  37170.98 2015     4    Friday   14      5
4     4/4/2015  36022.90 2015     4  Saturday   14      6
5     4/5/2015  28979.28 2015     4    Sunday   14      0
6     4/6/2015  28416.63 2015     4    Monday   14      1
7     4/7/2015  34945.63 2015     4   Tuesday   14      2
8     4/8/2015  17003.61 2015     4 Wednesday   14      3
9     4/9/2015  40903.74 2015     4  Thursday   15      4
10   4/10/2015  34091.52 2015     4    Friday   15      5
```

**][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2k7X.png)

weekavg output :

```
..
...
42      42 36857.81
43      43 35191.18
44      44 37929.33
45      45 37601.31
46      46 37536.39
47      47 38021.44
48      48 38130.23
49      49 40730.46
50      50 35682.76
51      51 37400.04
52      52 38200.43
53      53 49619.85
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: You'll have to tease the week for a given year out of the sale date for each row.  Once you have that, it's a simple group by and average calculation.

Comment: Thankyou @akrun! It worked. I am still figuring out stackoverflow, I shall put a better sample the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to also have `year` in the grouping

```
aggregate(Amount~ week + year, data = dod, mean)
```

Comment: Thankyou @akrun! It worked. I am still figuring out stackoverflow, I shall put a better sample the next time

Comment: @9minus4  Thanks.  In this case, it is easier to understand but in general, it would easier for others to test when the data is there.